# Accounting system database desgn Company Vendors Customers

Tags: database

I'm working on a project which is a mix of an accounting system and an e-commerce in order to allow a company to:
-Sell products to customers
-Buy products from vendors
-Store all accounting data using a new standard for data exchange between customer and vendors but that is not the main topic

The key point is that a company can have both customers and vendors and for this reason, the same company can be a customer or a vendor for the other part too.

My idea was to create three tables: Company, Customer, Vendor so that for each company I can keep track of vendors and customers but I cannot find a way to properly design it because the three tables are exactly the same objects with the same attributes.

My other solution would be to have two tables: Company and Contract.
In the contract table I'd have two columns 'VendorID' and 'CustomerID', both columns are connected to the Company table so that when I want to retrieve my customers I'd just filter the column 'VendorID' with my company ID and for the vendors the way around.

Am I following the right approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go the route of having a

Company table with the values and in that you have a key some 'Type' table.
So you can have your company table with your records and then if the 'typeid' is 1 then it is a vendor record. if its 2 it is a customer record

In the type table you have

id, desc

1, vendor

2, customer

Comment: But the same company can be a customer and a vendor at the same time. Let's say we have 3 companies in our db, company a has company b as customer and company C as vendor. In that case, company A is a customer of company c and  a vendor for company B.